# How to create Identical server and client side physics loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, client-server, synchronization

I am making a multiplayer snake game but the problem is that after beginning each game the server side snake which is created as a copy after the first player joins becomes altered either because the loops started at different times or because they are running at different speeds and after thinking for a couple days am still wondering how I can keep them in sync.

Comment: The server snake is a copy of the client? Can you explain a little further?

Comment: @eshortie what I mean is that the when the client connects it sends a copy of its self to server loop so that the server can run the loop in parallel to prevent cheating but the problem is that after that point the snakes go out of sync

Comment: Naturally this will occur if a client can manually perform input to control the snake. I assume you mean you want to match the server velocity, position, acceleration etc. with the client to have some form of deterministic behaviour i.e you know approximately where the client should be based on these variables. 

You'll need to pass these variables (and ensure you control them). As far as sync goes you'll need to account for the client-server ping.